# Magento 2: How to get product name by sql query using product ID

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql

I want to access the product names by query database using product ID. How can I achieve it?

Comment: u want sql query or Magento default way

Comment: i want sql query . I know the default way.

Comment: why do you want using SQL query?

Comment: I want to access the product names outside magento without using api.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Magento uses an EAV table structure for products. Names are stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. If you have the product ID **X**, you can query this table directly:

```
SELECT entity_id, value, store_id FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
  WHERE entity_id = X AND attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute
    WHERE entity_type_id=4 AND attribute_code='name'
  )
```

The subquery determines the attribute id for "name", entity_type_id 4 is always the type ID for products.

Note that in a multistore setup you might get multiple values per product. Pay attention to the "store_id" column. "0" stands for the default value.

Answer (score 4):

If your product's id is 1234:

```
select value from catalog_product_entity_varchar left join eav_attribute on
    eav_attribute.attribute_id = catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id
where
    eav_attribute.attribute_code='name' and 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id=1234
```

Comment: there is no `row_id` column, use `entity_id` instead of `row_id`.

Comment: In Magento 2 you have row_id

Comment: what? can you share screenshot of your database table?

Comment: Magento EE has row_id.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query to find name from product_id

> SELECT `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE entity_id=2
>   AND (attribute_id IN(SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE
>   `attribute_code` = "name" AND `entity_type_id` = 4))

Change `entity_id=2` as per your product id

Answer (score 1):

```
$_connection = $this->mc_get_obj(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);//get class

$db_connection = $_connection->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);//connection

$category = $db_connection->fetchAll('select * from '.'`catalog_product_entity_varchar` '.'left join '.'`eav_attribute` '.'on '.
'`eav_attribute`.'.'`attribute_id`='.'`catalog_product_entity_varchar`.'.'`attribute_id` '.'where '.'`eav_attribute`.'.'`attribute_code`='.'"name" '.'and '. '`catalog_product_entity_varchar`.'.'`entity_id`='.$vi['product_id']);
```

Comment: ------  sql:
select * from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` left join `eav_attribute` on
    `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`attribute_id`
where eav_attribute.`attribute_code`='name' and 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.`entity_id`=2082

Comment: public function mc_get_obj($class)
    {
        return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get($class);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this also,for single record, X is your product_id you have to replace it by your own product id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id=X AND (attribute_id IN(SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE  attribute_code = "name" AND entity_type_id = 4))
```